# How to group alphanumeric permissions

Tags: permissions

As an addition to my previous question: [Which is more widely used: chmod 777 or chmod a+rwx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153539/which-is-more-widely-used-chmod-777-or-chmod-arwx).

If I were to use the chmod a+rwx (which I wouldn't in the real world) format, but I wanted to use the alphanumeric value of 755.

How would I write that out?

e.g.:

```
$ chmod u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx
```

That just seems such a long expression.

Comment: this seems to work perfectly fine ? have you tried it ?

Comment: @Archemar, no I haven't, as it was part of the question. But surely there is shorter way to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all the users' `r` and `x` permissions use `a+rx` and then you'll just need to add `u+w` for the owner's permissions to grant write access.

```
$ chmod a+rx,u+w ...
```

This will grant `r` and `x` to every one, and just `u+w` to the owner.

Comment: OK that is an easier way to write it. Thanks.